# Cache-Control http header. header will return private when you are in debug mode and public when you are not in POSTMAN

Tags: c#, .net, postman

Cache-Control http header.  header will return private when you are in debug mode and public when you are not.  How to make Cache-Control http header will return public when you are not in debug mode.

ASP.NET debugging should be disabled for all applications deployed in a production environment.

I have disabled debugging for an application, set the debug attribute to false in the "Web.config" file: and enabled retail mode in the "machine.config" file for production environments:
Im still getting private. please help me on this.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
[web.Config]   [machine.config] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiTYv.png)